# Getting the correct errorformat for neomake

Tags: vim, neovim, neomake

I'm working on making a custom neomake maker for markdown using the tool [alex](http://alexjs.com/) but having a hard time figuring out the correct `errorformat` for it. Doing some debugging, it seem neomake returns the following information

```
Neomake [2.587]: [1.6] stderr: alex: ['test.md', '  1:5-1:14  warning  `boogeyman` may be insensitive, use `boogey` instead  boogeyman-boogeywoman  retext-equality', '', '⚠ 1 warning', '']
Neomake [4.431]: [1.6] exit: alex: 1
Neomake [4.431]: [1.6] alex: processing 4 lines of output.
Neomake [4.432]: [1.6] Removing invalid entry: test.md ({'lnum': 0, 'bufnr': 0, 'col': 0, 'valid': 0, 'vcol': 0, 'nr': -1, 'type': '', 'maker_name': 'alex', 'pattern': ''})
Neomake [6.404]: [1.6] Removing invalid entry:   1:5-1:14  warning  `boogeyman` may be insensitive, use `boogey` instead  boogeyman-boogeywoman  retext-equality ({'lnum': 0, 'bufnr': 0, 'col': 0, 'valid': 0, 'vcol': 0, 'nr': -1, 'type': '', 'maker_name': 'alex', 'pattern': ''})
Neomake [7.837]: [1.6] Removing invalid entry:  ({'lnum': 0, 'bufnr': 0, 'col': 0, 'valid': 0, 'vcol': 0, 'nr': -1, 'type': '', 'maker_name': 'alex', 'pattern': ''})
Neomake [8.669]: [1.6] Removing invalid entry: ⚠ 1 warning ({'lnum': 0, 'bufnr': 0, 'col': 0, 'valid': 0, 'vcol': 0, 'nr': -1, 'type': '', 'maker_name': 'alex', 'pattern': ''})
Neomake [9.469]: [1.6] alex: completed with exit code 1.
Neomake [9.469]: File-level errors cleaned in buffer 1
```

And the most successful format I've gotten so far is `errorformat = %I%f`, but that doesn't feel like the right direction.

Any ideas/tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind getting inspiration from the [competition](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/1557), something like this might work:

```
let errorformat =
    \ '%P%f,' .
    \ '%-Q,' .
    \ '%*[ ]%l:%c-%*\d:%n%*[ ]%tarning%*[ ]%m,' .
    \ '%-G%.%#'
```

Alternatively, you could use the [alex plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/textlint-rule-alex) for [textlint](https://textlint.github.io/).  As it turns out [textlint](https://textlint.github.io/) is a much juicier target, and it has a nicer output format.